# Android Automatic Task in a specific time

Tags: android

I am new in Android development. I am developing a twitter client. I would like to send a tweet at every morning at 8. I want to set the schedule like Alarm. How can I do that ? I will be happy if you point me to some examples or other resources. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of the AlarmManager:

```
private void daylyTask()
{
    daylyBR = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override public void onReceive( Context context, Intent _ )
        {       
            //Do something
            Log.d(TAG, "daylyTask uitgevoerd.");
        }
    };

    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver( daylyBR, new IntentFilter("yourApp.blah") );


    daylyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent("yourApp.blah"), 0 );

    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.set(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE, 0);

    // set alarm to fire 5 sec (1000*5) from cal repeating every 86400000L ms (1 day)
    manager.setRepeating( AlarmManager. RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis() + 5000L,  86400000L,  daylyPendingIntent );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out **[AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)**.

*Alarms (based on the AlarmManager class) give you a way to perform time-based operations outside the lifetime of your application. For example, you could use an alarm to initiate a long-running operation, such as starting a service once a day to download a weather forecast.*

Answer (score 0):

Look up the AlarmManager API.  I have used it to do things like what you are describing.

Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html